# Javax.Persistence.Tuple, how to mock data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, mockito

I have an repository method that returns List, which under the hood uses CriteriaQueryTupleTransformer.TupleImpl.
In tests I want to mock Repository and on Repository.method return predefined mocked data.

Something like this:

```
MyRepository myRepository = mock(MyRepository.class);
List<Tuple> = new ArrayList<>();
Tuple tuple = TupleImpl.Builder() //TupleImpl is private class and has no Factory or Builders
            //.addMockedData()
            //.addMockedData()
            .build();

tuples.add(tuple);
//add more mocked data

when(myRepository.findByIds(any())).thenReturn(tuples);

//Assert business logic that everything 
//went as expected when a specific Tuple structure was returned by repo
```

My main problem here is that I need to instantiate CriteriaQueryTupleTransformer.TupleImpl which is any private class, and I couldn't find any Builders or Factory methods for easy creation.

Comment: Why don't you mock the Tuple interface then?

Comment: This is what i did in the end, don't know why it didn't occur to me in the first place. Thx for help!

Comment: @LukaŠpoljarić it would be useful for others (like me) to see how you did it. Besides, I would upvote the question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did what you said in a comment. Answering here so people see what the solution looks like. Using Mockito.

```java
    private Tuple mockedTuple;
    private List<Tuple> tupleList;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockedTuple = mock(Tuple.class);

        tupleList = new ArrayList<>();
        tupleList.add(mockedTuple);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTuple() {
        when(mockedTuple.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(1);
        when(repository.something(any())).thenReturn(tupleList);
        
        // assertions
    }
```